# Cannot write integer to an offset within a buffer (char*)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memcpy, memset

I'm trying to write an `unsigned integer` to a specific offset in buffer in my C program. The buffer is typical 1 byte `char *` buffer.
I'm using `memcpy` to do this with some pointer arithmetic to point `memcpy` destination to a particular offset withing that buffer.

**Code:**

```
char* ph = (char*) malloc(4096);

//Init buffer with '\0'
memset(ph, '\0', 4096);

//Set int to be written
unsigned int tupleCnt = 4;

//Write to 4th byte offset (int* + 1)
memcpy(((int*) ph) + 1, (void *) &tupleCnt, sizeof(tupleCnt));
```

However, this doesn't write anything to this buffer.

Here's the hexdump of the file to which this buffer is written:

```
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
               ^
```

---

**If I write it to 0th offset, it works:**

```
//Write to 0th byte offset (int* + 0)
memcpy(((int*) ph) + 0, (void *) &tupleCnt, sizeof(tupleCnt));
```

Here's the hexdump:

```
0000000 0004 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
          ^
```

---

By the way I'm using `fwrite` to write this buffer to file, if it makes any difference.

```
fwrite(ph, 1, strlen(ph), fp);
```

---

I also tried using byte by byte increment on char* pointers, it didn't help either.
For example:

```
//Write to 4th byte offset (int* + 1)
memcpy(ph + 4, (void *) &tupleCnt, sizeof(tupleCnt));
```

---

Thanks in advance!
Or is there any other way to write int (or any numeric) values to char* buffers? Except int to string conversation, which I really want to avoid. I think it's too much overhead and naive method. :)

Comment: You need to use bitwise manipulation to store integers in a byte buffer in a portable way.

Comment: `strlen(ph)` is going to stop counting when it reaches a null byte. (That’s what it’s for.)

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Pick a language! It looks like C, btu you should not cast the result of `malloc` & friends (or `void *` in general) in C.

Comment: your code is good. the only problem is in `fwrite()` function do not use `strlen()` but the number of bytes you want to save, also. in your case use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to avoid initialization to zero. and finally do not cast `calloc()` and `malloc()`

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I'm new to C/C++ world, I usually confuse between two practices and constructs. Can you please elaborate more what's wrong here? Is it just wrong standard wise or any technical reason? Thanks!

Comment: For a starter: I repeat: There is no language C/C++!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem not in `memcpy` but in the way you write to file:

```
fwrite(ph, 1, strlen(ph), fp);
```

this code write 0 bytes, because of `strlen` return count of bytes from begin to first `'\0'` in your case it zero bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen(ph)` will stop counting when it sees a null character.
Since you have zeroed out the buffer, `strlen(ph)` returns zero when you write on the 4th byte offset but not when you write on the first byte offset. Use `fwrite(ph, 1, 4096, fp);`

Also to write integer you can use this

```
int *ih = (int*)ph;
ih[1] = tuplecnt;
```